# Quasi-finite over a point implies quasi-finite in a neighbourhood.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading O. Debarre's *Higher-dimensional algebraic geometry*, and in **Lemma 1.15** there is an argument, that a proper surjective morphism $p: Z \to Y$ of varieties, which has a finite fiber over a point $y_0 \in Y$ is actually a finite morphism over a small neighbourhood $Y_0 \subset Y$ of $y_0$.

I wonder why this is true. I think it suffices to show that $p$ has finite fibers in a neighbourhood of $y_0$, because properness is local in the base, and proper + quasi-finite implies finite (Hartshorne, Exercise III 11.2).

But why is it true that $p$ has finite fibers in a neighbourhood of $y_0$?

Comment: This follows from upper semicontinuity of fiber dimension

Comment: Ah yeah. Do you know if this is covered in Hartshorne? I only found semicontinuity of dimension of sheaf cohomology. Is fiber dimension a corollary of this, or do I have to read EGA IV, 3.1.3?

Comment: I don’t have Hartshorne on me right now but I don’t remember it being in there (it’s been a long time though). It’s an exercise for the projective case in Vakil’s notes I think